# How can I query NOT IN from an array?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
 const friendIds = friends.rows.map((friend) => friend.friend_id);

 console.log("list", friendIds); //list [ 50, 51 ]

 const users = await pool.query(
        "SELECT * FROM super_user WHERE user_id NOT IN(ARRAY[$1])",
            [friendIds]
        );
```

I want to query all users where the user_id does not equal any of the items in the array.

for some reason, even chat GPT is unable to give me a good solution

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<> ALL()`

```
SELECT * 
FROM super_user 
WHERE user_id <> ALL(ARRAY[$1])
```

Answer (score 0):

By Using ALL

```
SELECT * FROM 
super_user 
WHERE user_id != ALL(ARRAY[$1])
```

By Using ANY

```
SELECT * FROM 
super_user 
WHERE NOT (user_id = ANY(ARRAY[$1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the doc, there's [9.24. Row and Array Comparisons](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html) showing examples of this: [online demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2Ky31dC1YRj9erLBXqNff3/3)

```sql
SELECT * FROM super_user WHERE not user_id = SOME(ARRAY[$1]);
SELECT * FROM super_user WHERE user_id <> ALL(ARRAY[$1]);
```

In [9.19. Array Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) you can find it's also possible to just `unnest()` the array and compare to the resulting list of elements or see if the `array_position()` of your element `is null`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM super_user WHERE not user_id in (select * from unnest(ARRAY[$1]));
SELECT * FROM super_user WHERE array_position(ARRAY[$1], user_id) is null;
```

Good to know what happens if you get a null on either side:

```sql
select null=any(array[1,   2]),--null, not false
       null=any(array[null,2]),--null, even though it's technically there
       1   =any(array[null,2]),--null, not false
       1   =any(array[null,1]);--true, even though there was a null to compare to
```